# Having Trouble Reordering Content on WooCommerce Single Product Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking to reorder the content of woocommerce single product page. I am using Storefront theme with Bookshop childtheme.

Basically, I want to add to cart button and product price to appear below the product title. By default, it appears below product summary. With the help of the code below, I have managed to move Add to Cart button on the desired location.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30);
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15);
```

However, when I apply the same code to change the position of Price, it doesn't work. Ideally, I want price to appear above add to cart button, therefore, I tried this code.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

Could somebody tell what I am doing wrong?